# Project Feasibility: Create File.csv from File.txt

Tags: c++, csv, arduino, excel-2007, sd-card

Good day!
I'm a noob in excel and I was hoping someone can enlighten me with my problem.
I have an arduino project that stores .txt file to an SD card.

This is the format:

```
pressureOne=0.0
pressureTwo=-2.5
pressureOne=1.1
pressureTwo=-2.5
```

I need to write it this way because I will use the last pressureOne and pressureTwo as an input. I can only identify them when I write it this way.

I want the arduino to get the values from the .txt file and create .csv file that changes the format to:

```
pressureOne  |  pressureTwo
0.0             -2.5
1.1             -2.5
```

Is this possible? Should I program the arduino or should I program the macro?

Comment: Why don't you write the file in that format to start with? What does `should I program the macro` mean?

Comment: I need to write it this way because I will use the last pressureOne and pressureTwo as an input. I can only identify them when I write it this way. The "program the macro" are just words that lets you know I don't know much about excel; all I know is you can use programming to change something in excel and that you use macro to program(?)

Comment: What I meant was, why are you creating the file with the format `pressureOne=0.0` in the first place if you need it in the second format (which isn't even a **c**omma **s**eparated **v**alue file)?

Comment: I need the first format for the arduino. The second format is for easy viewing and graphing.

Comment: Why not just write both?

Comment: Now why didn't I think of that? *facepalm* I'll save myself from worrying about the code. You're a genius. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using the [Arduino SD card library](http://arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/ReadWrite), you could pre-format the lines written to your file and then save it as .CSV instead of .TXT.

From the Arduino SD lib code example:

```
myFile = SD.open("measurements.csv", FILE_WRITE);

  // if the file opened okay, write to it:
  if (myFile) {
    Serial.print("Writing to measurements.csv...");

    // create the string to be written to the file
    CSVLine = pressureOne
    CSVLine += ","
    CSVLine += pressureTwo
    CSVLine += "\n"

    myFile.println(CSVLine);
    // close the file:
    myFile.close();
    Serial.println("done.");
  } else {
    // if the file didn't open, print an error:
    Serial.println("error opening measurements.csv");
  }
```

Note this code is untested as I do not have an Arduino handy...

Best of luck with your project!